Telebot (Telegram bot). User id seems to vary in different parts of code
For example I get message.from_user.id in 4th line of my code, but when I do it in 104th line of code it's already different. Most interesting part is that it actually doesn't change if you ONLY do message.from_user.id in certain part of code and not in different parts of it
I tried checking if maybe I get the wrong message, but it's actually user's one. For example, it can be first_name = "hi", id = "293939", but first_name = "hi", id = "562346" in another part of code
